# Why is comparing strings 0(n), but comparing numbers 0(1)?

Tags: javascript, computer-science, equality

I understand that to compare two strings for equality, the interpreter has to iterate through both strings and compare each character.

That would make the time complexity `0(n)` where `n` is the length of the shortest string.

However, comparing two *numbers* for equality is `0(1)`.

Why is that? Wouldn't the interpreter have to iterate through every number to check for equality?

Comment: What is there to iterate on a number? A number is just the value: `2` for example, is not `3`. That's it. Similarly `123` is not `124`. A string is a collection of characters `"abc"` is different to `"abd"` but you do have to check each character.

Comment: Because comparing numbers is an CPU operation that compares 8/16/32/64/128 bit in parallel in one command.

Comment: Computers have intrinsic operations that compare entire number values quickly.

Comment: If you're working in a language like Erlang with infinite-precision integers, numeric comparisons are indeed O(n)

Comment: Also instead of "through every number" you probably mean "through every digit"

Comment: @Pointy: that isn't actually relevant to the O(n) vs O(1) question. Computers also have intrinsic string comparison instructions, they just happen to run in non-constant time.

Comment: @JoachimSauer well your statement is not logical; the point is that iteration over the contents of multiple memory locations is different than not having to do that. Of course there's nothing wrong with deciding that number comparison is O(n) *philosophically*, independent of what actual computers do, though of course "number" often means "a number with a fixed maximum number of bits" so O(1) is probably more correct.

Comment: @Pointy: what I'm saying is that the *existence* of "intrinsic operations" is not a valid argument for anything being O(1) as there are variable-runtime operations (or opcodes) on many modern CPUs.

Comment: @JoachimSauer sure; this is clearly a question from a newcomer to computing, so the fine distinctions between instructions that operate in a fixed number of cycles and those that intrinsically iterate through memory are probably more information than what's required. Of *course* I know that there are such things, but they're *different* in exactly the sense of what this question is asking.

Comment: @Pointy: That would be O(log(n)), because n number's length is proportional to log(n).

Comment: @Nyos it depends on what you call `n`. If it's the raw number of digits (in whatever base), then it's just that, If it's the "size" of the number in some base, then yes it's log n.  This is all completely pointless given the context of the actual question here. Note that the OP has not commented *at all* in this discussion; it's way over the level of understanding that the OP has.

Comment: @Pointy JavaScript also supports [arbitrary-precision math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) so comparing those `BigInt`s is also O(n)

Comment: @phuclv yes see one of my comments directly above

Comment: @Pointy I'm addressing what you said *"If you're working in a language like Erlang with infinite-precision integers"* since nowadays js also has built-in support for arbitrary-precision numbers

Comment: Yes, good point. The OP is a beginner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Numbers in computers are usually handled in fixed-size units. A `int` might be 32 or 64 bits in any given language and/or compiler/platform combination, but it will never be variable-length.

Therefore you have a fixed number of bits to compare when comparing numbers. It's very easy to build a hardware circuit that compares that many bits at once (i.e. as "one action").

Strings, on the other hand, have inherently variable lengths, so you just saying "string" doesn't tell you how many bits you'll have to compare.

There **are** exceptions however, as there are variable-length numbers, usually called something like `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` which will behave very similar to `String` comparison as it might end up being O(n) to compare two `BigDecimal` values for equality (where n is the length of the `BigDecimal`s, not either of their numeric values).

Comment: Does the presence of the javascript tag make any difference to this answer? In javascript they have the `===` and `==` operators, where the `==` operator allows for doing something like `1 == '1'` which will evaluate to true, but the docs are very vague as to what each of the operands are converted to before the comparison is done. So in this case, if they are converted to string, the comparison may not be doing integer compare but rather string compare

Comment: @smac89: JavaScript uses a single numberic type which is a fixed-size floating point number, so it makes no difference for comparison. Yes, *before* comparison you might need to do some conversions that may or may not be doable in O(n), but IMO that's not really part of the comparison.

Comment: @smac89 "*but the docs are very vague as to what each of the operands are converted to before the comparison is done*" [the docs are VERY explicit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using) in how the comparison between different types should be done.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for the link. So it looks like string is converted to number, which is still `O(n)` and that's my point with bringing this up especially when it is javascript involved.

Comment: @JoachimSauer `JavaScript uses a single numberic type` that's not correct. [BigInt is now a built-in type in JavaScript](https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/09/javascript-bigint.html)

Answer (score 3):

*Usually* programs represent numbers as fixed-sized data structures (binary values, which is why you may see their sizes described in bits).  Being fixed-size, comparisons would take a constant amount of time and be O(1), which is one of the benefits of such a representation.  A downside would be a limit on the range of values that can be represented.

An alternate representation that lifts this restriction, allowing for an arbitrarily-large range of numbers, would thus no longer be fixed in size, and no longer be O(1) to compare.

Answer (score 0):

## String

String comparisons are typically a linear scan of the characters, returning false at the first index where characters do not match.

The time complexity is O(N) and the actual time taken depends on how many characters need to be scanned before differences statistically emerge.
There isn't a simple answer, but the answer is nevertheless obvious ;-)

## Numbers

if two integers are in equal, it's impossible to know without comparing all their bits. So in case of equality, the time needed is proportional to the number of bits (which is proportional to log(abs(N)) if N is one of the comparands).

If they're not in fact equal, there are many cases, all relevant to implementation internals. Long ints are stored as a vector of "digits" in a power-of-2 base. If the vectors don't have the same lengths, then the ints aren't equal, and that takes constant time.

But if they are the same lengths, then the "digits" have to be compared until finding the first (if any) mismatching pair. That takes time proportional to the number of digits that need to be compared.

Comment: Digits aren't compared. Bits are compared.  And the bits are compared as an atomic group. No computer compares bit 1, then bit 2, then bit 3, then bit 4.  Depending on the particular instruction used and the capabilities of the processor, they compare 8 bits, or 16 bits, or 32 bits, or 64 bits, etc., as a single operation.  There is _no_ digit-level comparison or the equivalent, it's on byte/word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we only use big-O notation when *n* can rise to obscenely large values, because big-O notation describes how the execution time grows as the input grows. For instance, when sorting a list, most of the best algorithms sort in `O(n log n)` - which means, and *only* means, that when the list is long enough, that the time it takes to sort it is proportional to `n log n`. When the list is not long enough, other factors (for instance, any time your algorithm might take to allocate extra space), become significant, and can potentially even take over the running time.

With JavaScript strings, `n` can indeed get arbitrarily large*, so we say the comparison takes `O(n)` time. But with JavaScript numbers (which are [IEEE 754 double-precision floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)), `n` has a maximum cap of 64 - 1 for a sign bit, 11 for an exponent, and 53 for significant digits**. Because of this, we know exactly how long it will possibly take for a number comparison to occur, and the best systems we have for comparing numbers of that exact size more or less run the same regardless of how many of those 64 digits each number actually has - hence, comparing these numbers in JavaScript is considered `O(1)`.

---

*Technically, there is an upper limit because RAM can run out. However, the language doesn't specify a maximum size for strings, and the `O(n)` part of string comparison dominates the execution time well before that happens.

**By the way, this does mean that numbers in JavaScript can't rise infinitely. Past a certain point, they start throwing away smaller digits (for instance, numbers above 2^53 can only be even, and numbers above 2^54 can only be divisible by 4), and when the number gets large enough, it rounds up to infinity. Conversely, if you divide a number over and over again to make it infinitesimally small, it will eventually round down to zero.